# Преобразовать в многомерный массив

Tags: php, массивы, сериализация

Нужно преобразовать строку в многомерный массив в такой вид

```
array(array('product'=>'рубашка', 'color='>'розовая', 'size'=>'43', 'count'=>'50'),
array('product'=>'рубашка', 'color'=>'розовая' , 'size'=>'45', 'count'=>'40'),
array('product'=>'рубашка', 'color'=>'розовая' , 'size'=>'46', 'count'=>'30')`
```

Строка выглядит так:

```
product => рубашка color => розовая size => 43 count => 50 product => рубашка color => розовая size => 45 count => 40 product => рубашка color => розовая size => 46 count => 30
```

Как вы уже поняли я сначало преоброзовал многомерный массив в строку чтобы сохранить запись в базе, но никак не могу его обратно "превратить" в многомерный массив.

Comment: если и хранить массив в бд, то нужно использовать `serialize() + unserialize()`

Comment: @Эдуард спасибо помогло. Вы лучший